# System.Threading.Timer: A second operation was started on this context with

Tags: timer, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have Console Application on .NET 5 which is Discord Bot.
While start the application i have the problem with this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on
> this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually
> caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of
> DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with
> DbContext

And this is happens in Timer

This is in constructor:

```cs
_approveTimer = new Timer(async delegate
            {
                await CheckApproveAsync();
            }, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

```cs
public async Task CheckApproveAsync()
{
    var pendingUsers = await _pendingUsers.GetAllAsync();

    if (pendingUsers is null || !pendingUsers.Any())
        return;

    Program.Log.Debug($"Checking {pendingUsers.Count} pending users...");

    foreach (var user in pendingUsers)
    {
        var expired = DateTime.UtcNow > user.ExpirationTime;

        if (!expired) continue;

        await _pendingUsers.DeleteWithDetachAsync(user);
        IonicHelper.GetGuildUserById(_mainGuildId, user.UserId, out var sgUser);

        try
        {
            var msg = await _messageService.GetMessageAsync("register-pending-expired", new FormatData(user.UserId));
            await sgUser.SendIonicMessageAsync(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await _serverHelper.SendLogAsync(_mainGuildId, "Error", $"{nameof(CheckApproveAsync)} - {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    var usersValidated = 0;

    foreach (var user in pendingUsers)
    {
        RequestResult codeResult;
        string code;
        try
        {
            (codeResult, code) = await GetThirdPartyCodeByEncryptedSummonerIdAsync(user.Region, user.SummonerId);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (code is null || codeResult != RequestResult.Success)
            continue;

        var sanitizedCode = new string(code.Where(char.IsLetterOrDigit).ToArray());

        if (sanitizedCode != user.ConfirmationCode)
            continue;

        var (requestResult, summoner) = await GetSummonerByEncryptedPuuIdAsync(user.Region, user.PlayerUUID);

        if (requestResult != RequestResult.Success)
        {
            await _pendingUsers.DeleteWithDetachAsync(user);
            continue;
        }

        var (rankResult, rankData) = await GetLeaguePositionsByEncryptedSummonerIdAsync(user.Region, summoner.Id);

        var soloqRank = GetRankModelFromEntry(rankData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.QueueType == "RANKED_SOLO_5x5"));

        var summonerIcon = GetSummonerIconUrlById(summoner.ProfileIconId);

        var lolData = new LeagueData
        {
            UserId = user.UserId,
            SummonerRegion = user.Region,
            PlayerUUID = summoner.Puuid,
            AccountId = summoner.AccountId,
            SummonerId = summoner.Id,
            SummonerName = summoner.Name,
            SummonerIcon = summonerIcon,
            SummonerLevel = summoner.SummonerLevel,
            SummonerRank = $"{soloqRank.Tier} {soloqRank.Rank}"
        };

        _ = IonicHelper.GetGuildUserById(_mainGuildId, user.UserId, out var sgUser);

        await AssignRoleFromRankAsync(sgUser, soloqRank.Tier);

        var data = await _leagueRepository.GetByIdAsync(user.UserId);

        if (data == null)
        {
            await _leagueRepository.AddAsync(lolData);
        }

        usersValidated++;

        user.SummonerName = lolData.SummonerName;

        await PostValidateAsync(user);
    }

    Program.Log.Information($"{usersValidated} users validated.");
}
```

I read that it can be problem that if some method is not awaited, but i've checked it's all awaited. Which suggestions about this?

Comment: Create `DbContext` on each timer call. IOW, you cannot use `_pendingUsers`, `_leagueRepository` etc. But If these objects are used only in this timer, ensure that you have guarded `CheckApproveAsync` from multiple reentrance.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv idk how to do it, i'm using repository for this. If i bring CheckApproveAsync to the semaphore, it's still get this error

Comment: Solved with creation new scope with repo in each method where using this repo, thanks!